# Randomly select objects once from deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays, random

I pretty sure my remainder operator is in the wrong place, I've tried a few different variations, program still runs but pulls the same card more than once:

```
Card [] deck = {card0, card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11, card12, card13,
        card14, card15, card16, card17, card18, card19, card20, card21, card22, card23, card24, card25, card26, card27, card28,
            card29, card30, card31, card32, card33, card34, card35, card36, card37, card38, card39, card40, card41, card42, card43,
            card44, card45, card46, card47, card48, card49, card50, card51,
        };
for (int i = 0; i<deck.length;i++){
    deck[i] = deck[i%51];
    }
for (int i = 0; i<deck.length; i++){
    index = (int)(Math.random()*deck.length);
    deck[index] = deck[i];

    System.out.println(deck[i] + " ");

    }
```

I know the deck isn't created in the most efficient manner, that's due to limitations of the assignment. I've only included a small piece of the code, because I think the issue is with my for loop and remainder operator.

Comment: `i%51` is a constant for every iteration

Comment: Please explain what your program is supposed to do, and then what the first for loop is supposed to do, and then what the second for loop is supposed to do.

Comment: `deck[0]=deck[0%51]` `and deck[1]=deck[1%51]` and so on

Comment: What happens if you get the same value for `index` in multiple iteration of the second loop? Your output deck will be shorter than the original one.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to randomly shuffle the deck and then output it in the shuffled order.

Have a look at `Collections.shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to do here, since **i%51** is always equal to **i** in this case:

```
for (int i = 0; i<deck.length;i++){
    deck[i] = deck[i%51];
    }
```

Now to generate a random number between 0 and 50, you need something like

```
int randomInt = (int)(50.0 * Math.random());
```

Thus you should use:

```
for (int i = 0; i<deck.length; i++){
    index = (int)((deck.length-1) * Math.random());
    System.out.println(deck[index] + " ");
    }
```

But be sure that, some duplicates you may see using this method. If you want each card to be drawn/displayed only once, then use **Collections.shufffle(..)**

```
List<Card> deckList = Arrays.asList(deck);
Collections.shuffle(deckList);
for(Card card : deckList){
  System.out.println(card);
}
```